# MS SQL DB design help

Tags: sql-server, xml, relations

I'm stuck with table design and query FOR XML

Sync engine for Ads requires XML schema in this format

```
<attribute1>value</attribute1>
<attribute2>value</attribute2>…
<lookup_list> 
<lookup_item code="installations">220</lookup_item> 
<lookup_item code="heating">228</lookup_item> 
<lookup_item code="permits">233</lookup_item> 
<lookup_item code="parking">162</lookup_item> 
<lookup_item code="garden">166</lookup_item> 
<lookup_item code="electronics">167</lookup_item> 
</lookup_list>
<attributeN>value</attributeN>…
```

That lookup list is separate table that looks like this:

```
Lookup_item_id  code            lookup_item_title
220         ad_flat.installations   Town gas
221         ad_flat.installations   City water
224         ad_flat.heating_type    gas
226         ad_flat.heating_type    wood
```

For normal attributes I created this FOR XML query with sub-query for images that are in other table,

```
    SELECT
    attribute1,
    attribute2,
    (SELECT
    images.image_name AS image
    FROM images
    WHERE images.realestateID = realestates.ID
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ) AS 'image_list'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
* 
FROM realestates) realestates
FOR XML PATH ('ad_item'), ELEMENTS, root ('ad_list')
```

but for this lookup_list I have no idea how to design table and relations for that and how to write a query FOR XML export, please if someone have an idea I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The inner part you can create like this

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(Lookup_item_id INT, code VARCHAR(100),lookup_item_title VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @table  VALUES
 (220,'ad_flat.installations','Town gas')
,(221,'ad_flat.installations','City water')
,(224,'ad_flat.heating_type','gas')
,(226,'ad_flat.heating_type','wood');

SELECT t.code AS [@code]
      ,t.Lookup_item_id AS [*] 
FROM @table AS t
FOR XML PATH('lookup_item'),ROOT('lookup_list');
```

The result

```
<lookup_list>
  <lookup_item code="ad_flat.installations">220</lookup_item>
  <lookup_item code="ad_flat.installations">221</lookup_item>
  <lookup_item code="ad_flat.heating_type">224</lookup_item>
  <lookup_item code="ad_flat.heating_type">226</lookup_item>
</lookup_list>
```

This you can integrate into your select within paranthesis like a column (*scalar sub-select*).